# Javascript array sorting using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting

I want to sort an array of phone numbers and have the length of the array outputted based on areacode. For example:

```
var nums = [
    8881756223,
    8881742341,
    9187221757,
    ...,
]
```

there are a lot more entries than that (roughly 1300) and its already in numerical order. However, what I want it to do is:

```
  1. look at the first 3 numbers of the first entry
  2. look at the next entries first 3 numbers
  3. if they are different, then splice the array, console.log new array.length 
  and console.log that area code
```

so for example, the first two numbers in the array i provided will be spliced into their new array, and the console output will be:

```
areacode: 888, length: 1
areacode: 918, length: 0
```

I know the regex to search for the first the numbers, but I don't exactly know how to splice them into their own arrays...Like i know, use splice, but comparing the two with logic statements, I've never had to do something like that before while using a regular expression.

what I have so far is this:

```
const patt = new RegExp('^\d{3}')

var newArr = nums.filter(x => patt)

for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++)
    console.log(newArr[i])
```

but this is spitting out the full number, not the area code its self. Of course ill be adding the logic to sort after i get it to just spit out area codes.

Comment: can you just give 15-20 rows of data so that i can test my solution

Comment: [`nums.map(x => ("" + x).replace(/^(\d{3})[^]*/, '$1'))`](http://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/xLus7p3n/2/)

Comment: Probaly a duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731334/js-array-sort-with-regex

Comment: yeah.

6143617235,
6143928156,
7401156789,
7409012350,
7402055551,
7602791265,
7602323866,
7602567867,
7602921268,
8035982163,
8031346664,
8059136465,
8501299919,
8562190540,
8568451921,
8568672222,
8562345783,
9189281004,
9193570918,
9190678129,

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this seems to have done it. Nice job, dang, i need to learn how to use regex..

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using

```
nums.map(x => ("" + x).replace(/^(\d{3})[^]*/, '$1'))
```

Here,

- `"" + x` will coerce the number to string
- `.replace(/^(\d{3})[^]*/, '$1')` will remove all chars keeping the first 3 digits (or the whole string upon no match).

JS Demo:

```js
var nums = [
    8881756223,
    8881742341,
    9187221757,
    1
];
var res = nums.map(x => ("" + x).replace(/^(\d{3})[^]*/, '$1'));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var nums = [
    8881756223,
    8881742341,
    9187221757
]

var prefixes = nums.map(x=>(x+"").substr(0,3));

var votes =  prefixes.reduce(
(votes, curr) => {
    if(votes[curr]) votes[curr]++;
    else {votes[curr] =1;}
    return votes;
}, {});

var ans = Object.keys(votes).map(x => ({areacode:x, length:votes[x]}));

console.log(ans);
```

`ans` will hold the value you require

vote counting technique i used is explained here https://igghub.github.io/2017/01/15/useful-js-reduce-trick/